# Standards for installing a jar into local repository

Tags: java, svn, maven-3, maven-plugin

I made changes to the source code of a certain project (that exists in maven repo) by taking its source code from svn and having some lines changed in it,
now I need to install this into our local repository so other people using it have access to this update, what are the recommended steps to install this into my local repo, shall i change the version ? shall it be a snapshot ? or shall i just build it with the same version. I just need more standards on doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely should not use the same version no. If you use the same version number there will be a lot of confusion as to which jar are you using? The one thats in the maven repo or your local repo. You don't want a person in the future looking at your dependencies and getting thoroughly confused.

Also to be make it absolutely clear, I would change the artifact id as well. Prefix it with your name or some name so that it can be easily distinguished.